# typescript multiple type but pass one type for a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

i have this function below and backend returne the `page` value sometimes as number and if there is no `next_page` available it returns `false` meaing two different type of data for a single parameter `page` but i wan't to run or execute the below code when there is a value not any boolean. how do i do that?

`handlePageChange` function is expecting a type `number`

do i have to check `if (typeof page === "number") return handlePageChange(page);`
or any other way of handling this code? im not willing to check it everytime.
[image]

Comment: Check if it's a boolean?  -`if (page === current_page || typeof page === "boolean") return;`

Comment: Can you make it `number | false` instead of `number | boolean`?  Also, please [edit] the question to make the code a self-contained plaintext [mre] other people can paste into an IDE to see what's going on for themselves.  Right now you have [an image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) which is not easily used by others. Please replace that with plaintext and make sure you provide definitions for your values/types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's answer what you find because lack of details.

But I create a code sandbox based on your use case, and no error on it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-forked-ovn1en?file=/src/index.ts
[image]

I hope it helps,

Best Regards

Comment: Oh, I just realize, it's exactly @caTS solution.